# Minimal eigenvalue inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

My problem is to show that $$\lambda_{\min}(PA) \leq  \lambda_{\min}((D-M)A) ,$$ where $A$ is an arbitrary $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $P$ is a diagonal matrix with $\frac{1}{A_{ii}}$ as the $i$-th diagonal element and $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the $i$-th diagonal element equal to $\sum_{j = 1}^n\frac{p_{ij}A_{jj}}{\det_{ij}}$ and $M$ is a symmetric matrix with $M_{ij} = \frac{p_{ij}A_{ij}}{\det_{ij}}$, where $p_{ij}$ are probabilities with $p_{ii} = 0,\, \forall i$,  $p_{ij} = \frac{1}{n-1}$ for $i\neq j$, and $\det_{ij} = A_{ii}A_{jj} - A_{ij}^2$ for $i \neq j$, and $\det_{ii} = 1$ for all $i$. $A_{ij}$ is the element on the $i$-th row and $j$-th column. I have tried many simulations and this statement always holds, even with some special cases $2$ can be substituted by arbitrary large constant, but I am not able to contstruct a proof except when $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: Note that standard notation is $n\times n,$ not $nxn.$ I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: I slightly modified your problem to an equivalent form so that it is more compact. Do your simulations, after converted to the present formulation, show the right hand side of the inequality is always $\ge1$? I suppose they do not, but I want to confirm.

Comment: Thanks @Hans, in general the right hand side is not always $\geq 1$, it would be very helpful, but it is not true.

Comment: I have posted my equivalent reformulation of your problem on mathoverflow.net https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289475/a-minimal-eigenvalue-inequality with reference to your question here, so as to capture more and expert attention and assistance. Hope you do not mind and find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an exploration. This gives a proof for $n=2$ and block diagonal $A$ with $2\times2$ blocks. Hopefully, someone will be inspired to find a proof for the general case.

---

$$A= \frac1{n-1}\sum_{i<j}A_{i,j},\quad D-M=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i<j}A_{i,j}^{(-1)},\quad P=\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i<j} \big(\text{diag}(A_{i,j})\big)^{-1}$$
where $A_{i,j}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with entry $(i,j)$ equal to entry $A_{ij}$, entry $(i,i)$ equal to $A_{ii}$ and entry $(j,j)$ equal to $A_{jj}$, and all other entries zero; where $A^{(-1)}_{i,j}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix the entries $(i,i),\,(i,j),\,(j,i),\,(j,j)$ of which equal to the corresponding entries of the inverse of the row $i$ column $j$ principal minor of $A$, and all other entries zero.

When $n=2$, $PA=\begin{bmatrix}1 & * \\
* & 1\end{bmatrix}$ which is positive definite. Its minimal eigvenvalue of is no larger than $1$ which is that minimal eigenvalue of its diagonal matrix $I$. $(D-M)A=I$. So the desired inequality holds.

When $n>2$, 
$$(D-M)A=\frac1{n-1}\Big(I+\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i<j,\,k<l}A_{i,j}^{-1}A_{k,l}\Big),$$
where exactly two of $i,j,k,l$ are equal.

Comment: Very good exploration, but unfortunately I cannot see the way how to finish proof. Just a technical detail, $A_{i,j}$ is singular matrix for $n \geq 3$, so by $A_{i,j}^{-1}$ you mean inverse submatrix $2 \times 2$and all other entries are zeros.

Comment: You are correct. I have revised my answer. Please review.